# How to change the axes on shap summary plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, shap

I am following the code listed [here](https://lucasramos-34338.medium.com/visualizing-variable-importance-using-shap-and-cross-validation-bd5075e9063a), just with slightly different values (so my code is exactly as described in the link).

My output looks like this:

[image]

Would someone be able to show me how to change the X axis (ideally automatically, as I have to make multiple plots for different data sets), so the data is less bunched up and the full plot is seen?

Answer (score 5):

With reference to the code linked in the question, you can try the following solution(s) just after `shap_values` are calculated:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
.
.
# Calculate shap_values
fig = shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], X_test, show=False)
_, h = plt.gcf().get_size_inches()
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(h*5, h)
plt.show()
```

**OR**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
.
.
# Calculate shap_values
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], X_test, show=False)
ax = plt.gca()

# You can change the min and max value of xaxis by changing the arguments of:
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 0.5) 
plt.show()
```

You can also combine the above solutions to get the best resolution for your result.

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69355851/7789963) for more information.